# Long polling with IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, long-polling

I have a ASP.NET 3.5 web application that uses long polling for chat. It long polls an asynchronous handler for new messages. Each request can last a maximum of 15 seconds before being closed and reconnected.

The application runs fine using Visual Studio Built-in web server but once deployed to the IIS (i.e. IIS 7.5 ) the long polling requests start getting aborted after i login around 10 users.

Please help.